# Properly reloading a QQmlApplicationEngine

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlapplicationengine

I have a QML-based app that loads a `main.qml` file from the file system like this:

```
myEngine->load("main.qml");
```

This works fine, but I'd like to "reload" the engine in case the main.qml was replaced with a newer version.

What I tried so far was calling `load()` again, assuming that the engine will automatically reset itself like in other Qt classes.

Unfortunately this is not the case. If I call the method again, another window will appear with the contents of the updated qml file, while the original window stays open and continues to display the old qml file.

To fix this I tried to call `load(QUrl())`, followed by `clearComponentCache()` and a final load call for the new file. This results in the same effect.

Any ideas how I can "properly" reload a QML engine while the application is running?

Comment: `clearComponentCache()` looks like it's only related to components, and hence doesn't account for instances of those components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try storing `myEngine` as a pointer on the heap, and deleting it after calling [quit()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#quit). Then you can reconstruct it to get the new version of the QML file.

If you don't want to do this for some reason (e.g. because you want to keep the window around or whatever), you might try using a `Loader` and loading the QML file that way. Your `main.qml` would then look something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Loader {
     source: "changing.qml"
}
```

Whenever you detect that `changing.qml` has changed, just toggle the [active](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#active-prop) property of `Loader` to trigger a reload of the file.

Comment: Duh. I guess I should pack up and go home. It's so obvious it hurts. Thanks! Here, have some rep points. :)

Comment: I was not able to do it in any way by using pointer and quit, I would call quit and the connect to the quit signal, trying to delete it would always result in crash, tried disconnect(), deleteLater() but to no avail, loader solution works perfectly

Answer (score 6):

Just saw this, but if you're still trying to figure this out - it's a three step process, and you have some of it.

1. You MUST close window created by the `QQmlApplicationEngine` first.  In my case I pulled the first root object off the `QQmlApplicationEngine` and cast it to `QQuickWindow`, then call `close()`.
2. Now you can call `clearComponentCache` on the `QQmlApplicationEngine`.

This is what my window closing code does (note that I gave my main window an `objectName`)

```
QObject* pRootObject = in_pQmlApplicationEngine->rootObjects().first();
Q_ASSERT( pRootObject != NULL );
Q_ASSERT( pRootObject->objectName() == "mainWindow" );

QQuickWindow* pMainWindow = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(pRootObject);
Q_ASSERT( pMainWindow );
pMainWindow->close();
```

The third step is, of course, to load your QML.

Later, I moved to creating a `QQuickView` window instead of `QQmlApplicationEngine`, so that I could just call `clearComponentCache` and then `setSource` (I didn't like the user seeing the UI window vanish and then re-appear.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! This is an excellent way to do it and I'll give it a shot. Meanwhile I have found another approach to do this: Since we are loading the QML files from the file system using a file name URL, adding a random "?nocache=1238123" to the end of the URL solved the caching/reloading issue as well. Of course this is not as deep of a "reboot" for the engine as your approach, but works so far.

Comment: Thanks for the nocache tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a file watcher:

*main.py*

```py
DEBUG = True


class EntryPoint(qtc.QObject):
    if DEBUG:
        qmlFileChanged = qtc.Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.qml_engine = qqml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
        self.qml_entry = str(PATHS.playground.resolve())
        self.qml_engine.load(self.qml_entry)
        if DEBUG:
            qml_files = []
            for file in glob.iglob('**/*.qml', root_dir=PATHS.QML, recursive=True):
                qml_files.append(str((PATHS.QML / file).resolve()))
            self.file_watcher = QFileSystemWatcher(self)
            self.file_watcher.addPaths(qml_files)
            self.file_watcher.fileChanged.connect(self.on_qml_file_changed)

    if DEBUG:
        @slot
        def on_qml_file_changed(self) -> None:  # pragma: no cover
            self.qml_engine.clearComponentCache()
            window: QQuickItem = self.qml_engine.rootObjects()[0]
            loader: QQuickItem = window.findChild(QQuickItem, 'debug_loader')
            qtc.QEventLoop().processEvents(qtc.QEventLoop.ProcessEventsFlag.AllEvents, 1000)
            prev = loader.property("source")
            loader.setProperty('source', "")
            loader.setProperty('source', prev)
```

*playground.qml*

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

Window {
    id: root
    width: 1200
    height: 900
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.accent: Material.Cyan

    Pane {
        anchors.fill: parent
        objectName: "_rootRect"
        Loader{id: loader
            objectName: "debug_loader"
            anchors.fill: parent;
            source:"anything.qml"
        }
    }

}
```