# Why does not QQuickWindow->close() remove the object from rootObjects?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qqmlapplicationengine

I am trying to switch between different QML files from C++. I use a QQMLApplicationEngine and I can load a new file using `engine.load(filename)`

Before I do this I close the current Window (QQuickWindow) using

```
QObject* pRootObject = in_pQmlApplicationEngine->rootObjects().first();
Q_ASSERT( pRootObject != NULL );
Q_ASSERT( pRootObject->objectName() == "mainWindow" );

QQuickWindow* pMainWindow = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(pRootObject);
Q_ASSERT( pMainWindow );
pMainWindow->close();
```

which I found here: [Properly reloading a QQmlApplicationEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196113/properly-reloading-a-qqmlapplicationengine)

This works, in the meaning that the window actually closes, but, and here comes the problem - the rootObject (from the QQMLApplicationEngine rootObjects) is not removed. So if I switch back and forth a few times the rootObjects list just grows.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`Close` is just visibly closing an object, but doesn't actually delete it. Call after `close`:

```
pMainWindow->deleteLater();
```

Comment: worked for me - i had a timer that just didn't stop. and now it does. :)